# What's the difference between c# winform call cmd and open cmd manually?

Tags: c#, git, cmd

I am trying open the cmd by winform,and execute `git` command.But,the cmd shows that the git can't be recognize.If open the cmd manually,it works.What should I do if I wanna make it in winform.

Comment: How are you attempting to open the git command in code? With `Process.Start("git.exe");`? If so you may need to include the full path to the git executable.

Comment: Actually,I write a `bat` file.Call the file in cmd.

Comment: proc.StartInfo.FileName = "git.bat"; proc.Start();

Comment: Make sure that you include the full path to the git.exe in your git.bat.

Comment: If my git full path is `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`.How to write `git status` command?

Comment: Add options.   There is nothing different calling cmd in a program or manually except the environment variables like path are not set.

Comment: But the words `Program Files` contains a blank.The cmd shows `can't recognize C:\Program`(My cmd is Chinese version,Idk the correct words in English).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `git <command>` on your cmd manually it checks your PATH-Entries to locate the `.exe` file connected to the `git` command.

`where git` shows you where the executable is located on your system.

When you open a batch-file or execute an command in another enviroment (maybe you changed user enviroment because you run the `winform` commands from your IDE opened as another user), where there is not entry for `git` set in PATH, you can't execute the `git.exe` like this.

To overcome such problems, it would be best if you address the full path to the `git.exe` in your scripts.

Use:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" status
```

Instead of:

```
git status
```

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here. Every process by default starts with the combination of the system and user environment variables, inheriting from the process that started it, and I'm not aware of anything within winforms that would mess with e.g. `PATH`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My bad, I wanted to explain it a little bit different then what I wrote earlier. I just wanted to point out that such errors occur when for example he changes user-enviroment. I thought that maybe he was executing the  `winform` commands in another user-enviroment based on execution from an IDE.